# is there anyway to SQL update multiple element in List without using for loops?

Tags: java, mysql, list, loops

I'm working on my function and it runs well but i want to optimize the method to get better performance, here's my code:

```
for (Foo foo: duplicateElement) {
            String replace = duplicateElement.getName()
                    .replace( split + name + split, split);
            duplicateElement.setName(replace);
            foo.updateFoo(duplicateElement);
        }
```

The code above runs, but can i somehow take the ***updateFoo*** SQL call out of the for loops and still make it work? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate this IODKU (upsert) query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl
        (key, col2, col3)
    VALUES
        (11, 22, 33),
        (43, 54, 65),
        ...
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        col2 = VALUES(col2),
        col3 = VALUES(col3) ;
```

This requires that the column `key` be `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY`.  It will try to insert the given rows, but discover that they exist.  Then it will switch to Updating the columns specified.

MySQL 8.0 needs this syntax instead:

```
        col2 = NEW.col2,
```